# How to format decimal in MVC3 with more than 2 decimals

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, formatting, editor, number-formatting

I have an entity that is managed by a WCF service, so the entity is generated through service reference so I cannot annotate it to specify data format.
It is decimal and must be formatted with 6 decimals.
How can I accomplish this in MVC3, in display and editor?

In display I could use

```
@Html.Display(format("{0:f4}", model.MyField))
```

It's not very elegant, but it's workable.
But how can I do this for formatting the editor with 4 decimals?

EDIT:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617397/html-helpers-for-decimal-type-and-formatting) answer to a similar question, but it gives me error in line

```
return html.TextBox(name, value, htmlAttributes);
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, in response to your EDIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it as follows:

1. For display I used

   ```
   @string.Format("{0:f4}", Model.KPINumber)
   ```
2. for edit I used

   ```
   @Html.TextBox("KPINumber", string.Format("{0:f4}", Model.KPINumber))
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier syntax:

```
@Html.Display(model.MyField.ToString("f4"))
```

If you want to display it in an editable textbox, you could do the same:

```
@Html.TextBox("myField", model.MyField.ToString("f4"))
```

Obviously, this doesn't enforce 4 decimals client-side, but it initially displays it with 4 decimals.

**[Edit]**: In response to your edit: [That question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617397/html-helpers-for-decimal-type-and-formatting) "accepted" answer obviously does not compile, and the comments indicate this too.
Take a look at [Gaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617397/html-helpers-for-decimal-type-and-formatting/7766382#7766382) because it fixes the compile errors and looks like it works.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, it actually doesn't display anything, neither in view nor in edit - the area is empty. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if `f4` is correct, I just copied it from your example. I usually use `D4` or `N4`.

Comment: Strange, it didn't display anything for me using this approach, but it gave me the idea to make it work. Thanks for suggestion.