# How can I turn a lambda expression specifying a property into an asp.net mvc compatible 'name' string representing the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Assume

```
string value = ViewModelObject.SomeList[n].AnotherList[m].SomeProperty.ToString() //value is '5'
```

I need to turn this:

```
Expression<Func<ViewModelObjectType, object>> exp = x => x.SomeList[n].AnotherList[m].SomeProperty
```

into

```
<input type='hidden' name='SomeList[n].AnotherList[m].SomeProperty' value='5'/>
```

where n and m are integers.

I'm betting someone's solved this before. I want to bind my javascript control to my page viewmodel in a type safe manner. I'm playing around with the expression classes now and I can extract the property as a string but the rest of it I haven't figured out yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want `name` to be `"SomeList[n]..."` instead of `"SomeList[0]..."`, e.g.?

Comment: n and m are some integer like 0

Comment: I know. But MVC generally binds well when you have property names that have constant integer values in the `name` property in HTML, instead of variable names.

Comment: I'm going to add the <input type=hidden name="foo.bar.Index" value='weirdindexvalue' /> so I can break free of the stiff index requirements, actually

Comment: The idea was to have my javascript control generate its own hidden inputs and keep them updated as the page changes. Sometimes they are deleted and in this case I wouldn't have to worry about regenerating inputs belonging to other controls of the same type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Html.HiddenFor` helper seems to do what you need:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SomeList[n].AnotherList[m].SomeProperty)
```

But if for some reason you cannot rely on what's already built into the framework you could always roll your own stuff using the [`ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428394(v=vs.118).aspx) method which is what the ASP.NET MVC built-in helpers are already using:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string Foo<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> ex)
    {
        return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
    }
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view use it like that:

```
<input type='hidden' name='@Html.Foo(x => x.SomeList[n].AnotherList[m].SomeProperty)' value='5'/>
```

Comment: Yes I was looking for a way around hidden for. I have some black magic to work.

Comment: Well, in this case you might also try the `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` method as shown in my answer. But I'd rather try to fight the black magic at its root rather than extending it.

Comment: indeed, you've been a great help. I don't want to fiddle with the expression classes.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use this courtesy of: [ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression) not returning the name of my property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534206/expressionhelper-getexpressiontextexpression-not-returning-the-name-of-my-prop)

```
static public string GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression p)
{
    if (p.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || p.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
    {
        p = Expression.Lambda(((UnaryExpression)p.Body).Operand,
            p.Parameters);
    }
    return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(p);
}
```

My NodeType was always evaluating as ExpressionType.Convert