# Html.DisplayFor decimal format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string-formatting

I have a decimal value for example: `59625879,00`

I want to show this value like this: `59.625,879` or `59625,879`

How can I do this with `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TAll, String.Format())` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617397/html-helpers-for-decimal-type-and-formatting

Comment: I saw it before. But is there any simple way? Dont I write format template in `DisplayFor` ?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Decorate your view model property with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute and specify the desired format:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal TAll { get; set; }
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TAll)
```

---

Another possibility if you don't want to do this on the view model you could also do it inside the view:

```
@Model.tAll.ToString("N")
```

but I would recommend you the first approach.

---

Yet another possibility is to write a custom display template for the decimal type (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyDecimalTemplate.cshtml`):

```
@string.Format("{0:N}", Model)
```

and then:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TAll, "MyDecimalTemplate")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this at view side, not with model?

Comment: No, I never said to do this on the model. You misunderstood my answer. I said to do this on the view model.

Comment: `DisplayFor` helper has paramater that is called `string TemplateName`. Could not I use this property to do this?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have int? property in model and when I use first approach it works in `DisplayFor` but `EditorFor` is empty, and one question how can i change value of the property like I have int? with value of 150 and I'd like to display 1.50

Comment: For anyone who landed on this (correct and good) answer but wants to know how else they can adjust the display format, check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Had to use `{0:N0}` in `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`