# How to use Model data in a view ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, model

I'm a beginner with ASP MVC and I'm trying to show data from a model in a view.
This is how I display the data :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Budget_Year)
```

But I don't know how to use this data, for example I tried to round up this result and I tried  naively :

```
@{ 
   double test = (modelItem => item.Budget_Year);    
   test = System.Math.Round(test , 2);
}
```

But I can't use it like that : *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'double' because it is not a delegate type*

Someone can explain me how to use this different items from my model in my view ?

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: don't put logic or any code(without helper method and html) in view page.

Comment: @BappiDatta I agree, but where am I suppose to round this value if I only want to display it rounded in the view ?

Comment: Ok,than round that value in controller and pass it with ViewData or ViewBag

Comment: @Alex If you want to use only rounded value - in your model `get` attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have many ways to do this more properly :

**use a ViewModel class**, where you have a property which is your Rounded value

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public double BudgetYear {get;set;}
   public double RoundedBudgetYear {get {return Math.Round(BudgetYear, 2);}}
}
```

and in View

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.RoundedBudgetYear)
```

or

Add a **DisplayFormat attribute** on your property

see [Html.DisplayFor decimal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067375/html-displayfor-decimal-format)

or

**Create your own HtmlHelper**, which will round the displayed value.

```
@Html.DisplayRoundedFor(m => m.BudgetYear)
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to declare what model you will actually be using and then use it as `Model` variable.

```
@model YourModelName
@{
    var test = Model.BudgetYear.ToString("0.00");
}
```

Comment: Ok, I get it, I'm in a loop @foreach (var item in Model) so I need to use item.Budget_Year. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to access a property of the model you can do it like this:

```
double test = Model.BudgetYear;
```

The lambda is only necessary if you're trying to have the user assign a value to it from the view.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in the view. Instead I would round `BudgetYear` in your model / view model and send it down to the View already rounded. Keep the `logic` in the controller / model and out of the view. This will make it easier to test as well