# Passing Dictionary or another list type throught TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to send `TempData` list to View.

```
Dictionary<string, string> allerts = new Dictionary<string, string>();

allerts.Add("alert-success", "Акция добавлена");

foreach(string error in result)
{
     allerts.Add("alert-danger", error);
}
TempData["allerts"] = allerts;
```

But `TemData` doesn't have an Enumerator.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do what? And what does an `Enumerator` have to do with it? You return your model to the view using `return View(allerts);` , not using `TempData`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I am not sure if you want alerts and error return codes in the actual viewmodel in this specific case. Nevertheless, I think it's good advise to let OP know there are alternatives.

Comment: @Stefan, Everything should be passed to the view via a view model (and `TempData` is designed for passing data between actions, not between an action and a view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in your view you can use it like this:

```
@{
     foreach (var item in (Dictionary<string, string>) TempData["allerts"])
     {

     }
 }
```

an alternative to make it more robust:

```
@{
     foreach (var item in TempData["allerts"] as Dictionary<string, string> ?? 
                                                  new Dictionary<string,string>())
     {

     }
 }
```

You might want to read a bit about MVC. Usually data is passed to the `View` through a `ViewModel`. But since it's about alerts, it might be justified to use a viewbag.

[How to use Model data in a view ASP MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688099/how-to-use-model-data-in-a-view-asp-mvc#16688233)

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/476967/what-is-viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata-mvc-option

[ASP.NET MVC - How exactly to use View Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548376/asp-net-mvc-how-exactly-to-use-view-models)