# Display a decimal field As Int in Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have razor code like this :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.sepordan_melk_foroshes.ghamat_total)
```

as a resault it display this :

```
123.00
```

how can i remove the last part and show it like this? :

```
123
```

I would be so grateful if anyone help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.DisplayFor decimal format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067375/html-displayfor-decimal-format)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Model.item.sepordan_melk_foroshes.ghamat_total.ToString("N")

@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.sepordan_melk_foroshes.ghamat_total)
```

Or you can change your model, and add the format decoration to the attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: It didn't Work :( it shows this Error message
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments