# Insert decimal value into SQL Server using EF 5 and MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, decimal

I have a problem with insert `decimal(10, 7)` value into SQL Server

When I'm trying to add number from an ASP.NET MVC view, `51.0492263` into database

In debugger I have number = `51.0492263`

But when I'm go to database, I have `51.0400000`

Why I got this result?

Someone help please me.

Comment: Show us how you're inserting the data into the database!

Comment: Is your model for Entity Framework, or are you using something else?

Comment: @hvd, yes im using EF 5 and MVC 4.

Comment: @marc_s what exactly you mean? Im trying to add decimal value from View, I have field for this @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Latitude)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default scale for Entity Framework, when using Code First, is 2. It's possible to use Code First with an existing database, but it's up to you to ensure that the database structure matches what EF thinks it should be.

Unfortunately, there isn't a ready-to-go attribute for specifying the scale. You'll have to use `DbModelBuilder`. In your context, you can put

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Device>().Property(d => d.Latitude).HasPrecision(10, 7);
}
```

Comment: thx for answer, I have one more question, when Im read this info from database got same problem, in debugger correct values, but on page have Latitude 51.05

Comment: Hmm strange, Im delete  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Latitude) and use @item.Latitude and all works fine :)

Comment: @NazarIaremii I'm not familiar with MVC, but I can imagine that it itself has some default formatting settings that get used with `DisplayFor`, that don't get used when you print the latitude directly. If that is correct, [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12067375/743382) may help you to get the formatting correct even with `DisplayFor`.