# Rounding a decimal in a table to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a table in my view with columns of numerical data. In the footer of my table I have a row containing the totals of each column. The totals are adding up correctly, but I want the vales in them to be rounded to 2 decimal places, eg instead of 47.4386, I want it to display 47.44.

Sample code:

```
<table class="display" id="dailyreporttable">


    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyReportDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Estate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BettingShop)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShopBalance)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCashIn)
            </td>
 }

    <tfoot>

        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="alignRight">@Model.Sum(item => item.ShopBalance)</td>
            <td class="alignRight">@Model.Sum(item => item.TotalCashIn)</td>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

Comment: [Html.DisplayFor decimal format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067375/html-displayfor-decimal-format)

Comment: Give the sample of your model? I cannot understand why the asnwer of NDC-1701-M didn't work for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <td class="alignRight">@Model.Sum(item => item.ShopBalance).ToString("N2")</td>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I get the error: "Method ToString has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)"

Comment: Is it possible, that item.ShopBalance and TotalCashIn are not numeric? What type are they? In my example it works fine.

Comment: They're both of type decimal

Comment: But decimal has an overloaded ToString Method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx There must be another error. What type is you model?

Comment: Suppose @Kevin made some  mistake in the model

Comment: Its actually a nullable decimal, if that makes any difference? eg
        public Nullable<decimal> ShopBalance { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Got it in the end, the values were actually nullable decimals so I had to do:

```
 <td class="alignRight">@Model.Sum(item => item.ShopBalance).Value.ToString("N2")</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<td class="alignRight">@Model.Sum(Decimal.Round(item => item.ShopBalance), 2)</td>
```