# Show Comma instead of dot in MVC according to Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Controller returns a decimal value eg: 1.00  I need to show it as

1,00 in the view according to the culture

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ValidateCouponCode","MyAccount")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{ "couponCode" :"' + couponCode + '", "lockerCost" : "' + lockerCost + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.unblockUI();
            $("#txtCouponValue").val(data.CouponAmount);
            $("#txtPaymentAmount").val(data.PaymentAmount);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error occurred");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There are lots of [plugins](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/input-format) that will help you do this.

Comment: According to which 'culture' (the servers, the browsers)? And what does the code you have shown have to do with displaying a value in the view?

Comment: Iam using spanish culture es-AR

Comment: What's the point of tagging the question with c# and showing jquery code instead? In c# you can use culture specific decimal formatting. Not sure what about javascript.

Comment: Check this link ....It will help you..........
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067375/html-displayfor-decimal-format

Answer (score 0):

You can either use int.ToString("#.0", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture) in server or you can use Number.prototype.toLocaleString() if you want it in client side if you're using client's local culture.